# Allowing user to Submit form once in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

i want that user can submit a particular form only once. Is it possible without any js,react.. actually by using django only ??
i have tried something like that --

```
def apply(request):
    p=0
    if request.method=="POST":
    p=1
     ...do something..
    else:
      ...do something...
```

i have tried to catch the value of p=1, and try to not return the html is it's submitted once , but each time reload makes the value of p=0.
i have to save the session ?? or what will be the right way to do this ?
can anyone suggest anything please?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding a field name `form_submitted` as [BooleanField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield) to your User model(by abstracting the based User model) to check and see if that user submitted the form. You can get the current logged in user from request.user.

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    # also do this if you have custom user model
    form_submitted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "users"
```

views.py:

```
def apply(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
       user = request.user
       if not user.form_submitted:
          # save the form
          user.form_submitted = True
          user.save()
       else:
          # this user already submitted the form
```

Comment: so after submitting the value will be True autometically ?

Comment: well yes because you updated the column value with save()